# Index Match with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I have a list of products ranked by percentile.  I want to be able to retrieve the first value less than a specific percentile.

```
Product Orders  Percentile  Current Value  Should Be 
Apples  192     100.00%     29             29
Apples  185     97.62%      29             29
Apples  125     95.24%      29             29
Apples  122     92.86%      29             29
Apples  120     90.48%      29             29
Apples  90      88.10%      29             29
Apples  30      85.71%      29             29
Apples  29      83.33%      29             29
Apples  27      80.95%      29             29
Apples  25      78.57%      29             29
Apples  25      78.57%      29             29
Apples  25      78.57%      29             29
Oranges 2       100.00%     0              1
Oranges 2       100.00%     0              1
Oranges 1       60.00%      0              1
Oranges 1       60.00%      0              1
Lemons  11      100.00%     0              2
Lemons  10      88.89%      0              2
Lemons  2       77.78%      0              2
Lemons  2       77.78%      0              2
Lemons  1       55.56%      0              2
```

Currently my formula in the "Current Value" column is: `=SUMIFS([Orders],[Product],[@[Product]],[Percentile],INDEX([Percentile],MATCH(FALSE,[Percentile]>$O$1,0)))` (entered as an array formula)

$O$1 contains the percentile that I am matching (85.00%).

The current value for "Apples" (29) is correct, but as you can see my formula is not producing the correct value for the remaining products as in "Should Be" but is returning "0".   Not sure how to set this up to get it to do what I need it to.  I tried several things with SumProduct but couldn't get that to work either.  I need someone with more experience to give me a hand on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the SUMIFS(), just the INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX([Orders],MATCH(1,([Percentile]<$O$1)*([Product]=[@Product]),0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter on exiting edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!...by the way, how do you attach a sample snapshot of your worksheet like that?

Comment: I think you have to have 50 rep to do it.  Otherwise you would upload it to imgur.com and link it in your post.

Comment: Why does it not work for me to just switch the "<" to ">" if I want to find the first number larger than a certain percentile?

Comment: @LorenS it should, did you remember the Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: Yes, but it still does not work for me.  Instead, It returns the largest number of every sequence.

Comment: You will need a different formula, or sort your data differently.  If you do not want to flip the sort so percentile is smallest to largest, then ask a new question.  Try using SMALL to get what you want.